# ScrollView inside TabLayout inside a fragment not scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-tablayout, android-nestedscrollview

## Solution:

As @[Divyesh Patel] said, I had to put out the `ViewPager` from the `AppBarLayout` in the `TabLayout fragment`.

NOTE: Remember to put the `height` of the `AppBarLayout` **from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`** after removing the `Viewpager`.

## Original question:

I found a lot of answers and I tried a lot of solutions but noone of them could help me.

My problem is a bit nested:

- I have an `Activity` with a `DrawerLayout`
- Then I have a `Fragment` filling the `Content view` which has a `TabLayout`
- Inside this `TabLayout` I have a `Fragment` showing a bounch of `TextViews`, `EditTexts`, `AutocompleteTextboxes` excetera.

My problem is that this Last `fragment` is **not Scrolling vertically**.

What I tried so far:
- Using `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`
- Adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in kinda all super layouts
- Managing the `Scrollbars` and `scroll directions`
- Changing `heights` from `wrap` to `match` and vice versa
- Working with and without `fillViewPort`

**My mainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/background_light_grey"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My tabLayout fragment**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="******">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/mTabLayout"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager"
        android:background="@drawable/background_light_grey"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/mViewPager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabInPlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/mViewPager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pin_blue"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/mViewPager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/complete"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**My last fragment, with all views** *(the one not scrolling)*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_light_grey"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context="**********">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
        <!-- lot of views, i cut them couse it was something near to 200 rows -->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks all for the help

Comment: did you try to remove CoordinatorLayout from fragment layout?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel thanks for replying, no I didn't because I need it for the fabs, don't I?

Comment: then put Viewpager outside of Appbar and check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40364464/6756514

Comment: @DivyeshPatel omg, I already tried it but at a second look I forgot to set the layout height of the appbar differently after the Viewpager's remove. It works, thanks a lot!!! I had to pause some minutes